# npm glob errors and unmet dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm

When I run `npm ls -g` [this is the output](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1261638/npm-ls-out.txt). Is there a way to correct all those errors? I'm trying to find a "npm install all dependencies [recursively]" type command.

I have tried `ulimit -n 64` (because I read somewhere in the npm issues that might help?). The following is the output when I run `ulimit -a`:

`core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 64
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 1
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 709
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited`

`$ node -v
v0.10.29`

Please let me know if I can provide any other information (and how to do so). Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried:

```
npm install -g npm

npm cache clean

npm cache clear
```

from [npm's troubleshooting page](https://github.com/npm/npm/wiki/Troubleshooting) and the errors [seem to have disappeared](https://www.dropbox.com/s/11b83fuh1w7k43o/npm.txt).

Comment: Thanks @JakXz! I was wrestling with switching my local copy of node from a manual install to homebrew for about an hour. Running ```npm install -g npm``` finally did the trick for me.